# Anti-seize on a slider pin?

Tags: brakes, maintenance, brake-calipers, grease, anti-seize

**Is there any circumstance in which it would be acceptable to put anti-seize on a slider pin (for a brake caliper)?**

A mechanic wrote this to me:

> "When slider pins are serviced, they are removed from the mounting bracket, buffed on a wire wheel and lubricated with anti-seize or a synthetic brake lubricant. Both options are acceptable (contrary to your Google search) and provided by Napa."

As the mechanic says, I've already done research on the topic. I could tell you what I found, but I don't want to do anything to compromise the neutrality of the answers.

I can at least show you what research I have done in order to make sure this question wasn't a duplicate:

- [What type of Brake Lube to use](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/32357/44515) (gives one  suggestion for a product to use on slider pins, but doesn't address the question of whether or not anti-seize would be acceptable).
- [What brake components need to be lubricated?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/6708/44515) (has anti-seize mentioned in two of the answers, but neither mention refers specifically to using it on the guide pins).
- [Replaced brake pads - one pad was full, the other was gone. Brakes now very hot after driving](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/6368/44515) (anti-seize is mentioned in association with guide pins in one of the answer, but there's a lack of details and this answer has a net score of 10 lower than the top-voted answer, so it seems relatively poorly received).
- [Sounds like brake disc is making contact with pad shims](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/40006/44515) (for completeness, I'm listing here the last thread from, the 6 results in my search for "anti-seize sliding pin" which might be interpreted by some as being relevant, but it seems a lot less related than the previous three that I listed here).
- [Squealing Brakes (2012 Chevy Cruze RS)](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/43704/44515) (searching "anti-seize guide pin" gave me two results, one that I already listed above, and this one, which I think is fair to say is not very relevant).

Comment: Interesting that the new logo is not showing up [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4hQS.png).

Answer (score 3):

What your mechanic told you seems to be spot on and good advice.

There is nothing wrong with putting anti-seize on the guide pins of a brake caliper. The idea is to ensure the caliper slides easily/freely without binding. Anti-seize should provide that without compromise. The only thing you have to look out for is to ensure you do not get it onto the rotor or friction surface of the pad. Either would compromise the stopping ability of the brakes. If you've ever dealt with anti-seize before, you'll know it tends to get everywhere. Care with handling fasteners which have been coated with anti-seize should be at the top of your list. If any does get onto either bit (rotor or pad), ensure you clean them with brake cleaner and a clean cloth prior to final installation.

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast reply! I suppose my next question would be, why this contradicts what almost everyone else seems to be saying? Apart from the risk of the anti-seize touching other parts that it's not supposed to (let's assume we're careful enough that this doesn't happen), the consensus seems to be that anti-seize congeals and will make the guide pins "sticky". It also seems to be strongly recommended *not* to use a product with petroleum in it, on anything touching rubber, and Permatex anti-seize does have petroleum in it. Why would one use anti-seize instead of a silicone grease?

Comment: If you have silicone grease, then use it. I use anti-seize because that's what I have. I've never had issues with it. Yes, anti-seize will dry out, but it's not the liquid in it which provides the lubrication. It's the metal particles (aluminum/nickel/copper, depending on the type) which provides the lubrication and ability to allow two pieces of metal to slide.  I've been told a lot of things not to do with anti-seize. I've not found anything credible which tells me why I can't and plenty of first hand experience to know I've not had any troubles using it.

Comment: Thanks so much! I don't want to ask too many follow-up questions, but I just want to clarify some things. (1) Using silicone grease would be better than using anti-seize (if both are available)? (2) there seems to be strong recommendations against using petroleum-based products on sliding pins due to the damage it can do to the rubber seals: are these not credible? (3) I don't see why the drying of certain parts of the anti-seize cannot counteract the lubrication that the metal parts provide, but nothing beats first-hand experience! How often do you re-grease the sliding pins?

Comment: As a general guideline, antiseize compound is  recommended for threaded parts like O2 sensors to prevent galvanic reaction, dissimilar metals reacting to each other creating a bond that can be difficult to break. Older engines using block oxide coated spark plugs threaded into aluminum cylinder heads would seize because steel and aluminum react. Some broke plugs from seizing and eventually learned to use antiseize. Now all spark plugs are nickel plated  (not chrome) and don't need antiseize. Buy brake grease formulated for brake lubrication. Silicone brake grease is best for slide pins.

Comment: @FDryer I wonder why that's a comment on this answer rather than a separate answer of its own?

Comment: Nothing wrong with using brake grease for lubricating your brake parts (as I alluded to). If you don't have it, there's nothing wrong with using anti-seize for the same purpose. Yes, grease is preferred, but anti-seize works just fine. The other thing about anti-seize or grease is to prevent corrosion, both of which work pretty good. And @FDryer ... anti-seize does a lot more than keeping spark plugs from seizing in the bore ... it seals the threads to help prevent escaping combustion gasses, help in heat transfer, and helps ensure good electrical conductivity.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I wonder how often you re-grease (or re-anti-seize) the sliding pins?

Comment: Only when I change pads or do work on the brakes.